# vector field plot with 2 matrices quiver

Tags: python, vector, plot, 2d

I have 2 nxn matrices, 1 containing the x-component of the vector field and the other the y-component. Additionally I have 2 lists of each length n with the x, and y position respectively. 
now I would like to create a grid with my x-y values from the lists as scale and the vector field consisting of the 2 matrices (the arrows should consist of the x,y position of each matrix) but it doesnt work. Im quite desperate already and hope Ill find help! thanks a lot!

plt.quiver(x,y,matrix1,matrix2)
plt.show()

, where x and y are lists of n and matrix 1 and matrix 2 are matrices of nxn

Answer (score 0):

This code correctly generates a quiver plot with data of the dimensions specified.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data
n = 10
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
matrix1 = np.random.rand(n, n) - 0.5
matrix2 = np.random.rand(n, n) - 0.5

# Create quiver plot
plt.figure()
plt.quiver(x, y, matrix1, matrix2) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Quiver plot]